# How do you embed latest tweet on a website?

Tags: twitter

On a site I'd need it to show the latest tweet from an account.

Previously, going to Twitter's Goodies page and limiting to one tweet, would accomplish this. Now there new version of Timeline embeds do not seem to have an option for this, so how is it accomplished? I can use the old version 1 embed I have saved but all old ones will stop working next year according to Twitters FAQs, so want to use the new version 1.1 code..

Below is the new code Twitter provides. Just need to know how/where to add "count=1" as I could with the original version.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/example" data-widget-id="0000000000">Tweets by @example</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 31):

Here is how to display the latest *n* tweets. Just change the value in data-tweet-limit.

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline"
      href="https://twitter.com/twittername"
      data-tweet-limit="1">
Tweets by @twittername</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  jQuery(function($){
    $(".tweet").tweet({
      join_text: "auto",
      username: "seaofclouds",
      avatar_size: 48,
      count: 3,
      auto_join_text_default: " we said, ",
      auto_join_text_ed: " we ",
      auto_join_text_ing: " we were ",
      auto_join_text_reply: " we replied ",
      auto_join_text_url: " we were checking out ",
      loading_text: "loading tweets..."
    });
  });
```

For more options go [HERE](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/)

Comment: You mean there is no longer a way to simply add "count=1" or such to the embed? Why in the world would twitter remove that feature and require using plugins or the api to just have a single latest tweet shown?

Comment: Great, if so can you then provide an example with the default new twitter code?